# dialog display automatically when i load web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When i load my web page, i have a dialog who open automatically.
I don't want that.

I put a image and when i click on it, i would like dialog open

my js

```
       $("#deleteReportButton").click(function() {
             $("#deleteReportConfirm").dialog("open");
        });


        $("#deleteReportConfirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete report": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

html part

```
       <div id="deleteReportConfirm" title="Delete report?" style="display:none">
           <p>....</p>
       </div> 

       <img id="deleteReportButton" src="/plato/resources/images/delete.png" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the autoOpen option and set it to false, this will stop it from opening when the page is loaded and only load when you call the open function.

```
$("#deleteReportConfirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete report": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Eh89t/1/

Comment: strangely, when i click to open this dialog, it closed immidiately

Comment: works fine for me check my jsfiddle i added. If its still closing when opened you have some other event that is closing it on open.